# Replace certain pixels by integers in numpy array

Tags: python, image, numpy, python-imaging-library, numpy-ndarray

I have made myself a numpy array from a picture using

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

image = Image.open(file)
np.array(image)
```

its shape is `(6000, 6000, 4)` and in that array I would like to replace pixel values by one number lets say this green pixel `[99,214,104,255]` will be `1`.
I have only 4 such pixels I want to replace with a number and all other pixels will be `0`. Is there a fast and efficient way to do so and what is the best way to minimize the size of the data. Is it better to save it as `dict()`, where keys will be `x,y` and values, will be `integers`? Or is it better to save the whole array as it is with the shape it has? I only need the color values the rest is not important for me.

I need to process such a picture as fast as possible because there is one picture every 5 minutes and lets say i would like to store 1 year of data. That is why I'd like to make it as efficient as possible time and space-wise.

Comment: What is the issue, exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you can use np.where for this:

```
>>> arr = np.array(image)
>>> COLOR = [99,214,104,255]
>>> np.where(np.all(arr == COLOR, axis=-1), 1, 0)
```

This will produce a 6000*6000 array with `1` if the pixel is the selected colour, or `0` if not.

Answer (score 0):

How about just storing in a `database`: the `position` and `value` of the pixels you want to modify, the `shape` of the `image`, the `dtype` of the array and the `extension` (jpg, etc...). You can use that information to build a new image from an array filled with `0`.